# socket.io client side in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Am I doing something wrong? When I run `node client.js`. I am getting this error message:

```
/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:358
  var listeners = server.listeners('request').slice(0);
                         ^
TypeError: Object http://localhost:8080 has no method 'listeners'
    at Server.attach (/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:358:26)
    at Function.attach (/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js:124:10)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:226:21)
    at new Server (/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:51:17)
    at Server (/web/ws/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:39:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/web/ws/client.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Here is my code:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io('ws://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.send('hi');
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      // my msg
    });
  });
```

Please suggest something. where I am doing the mistake ?

Comment: Did you try just `var socket = io();`, without the adress ?

Comment: no.. let me try. I'll let u know

Comment: After calling `node client.js` I am getting nothing. Even not getting any error

Comment: Use [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to use **[socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)** package which is for configuring the server.

Instead you need to use **[socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)** package to be able to act as a client.

You can find usage examples by following provided links.